# Grouping data based on two columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below input

```
Country1    Country2
A   Z
B   Y
C   X
D   W
X   C
W   D
A   Z
```

I want to group data considering round trip as one. For eg: Considering C to X and X to C as 1.

```
Country1    Country2    Count of Trip
A   Z   2
B   Y   1
C   X   1
D   W   1
```

How do i group round trips together in a query.

Comment: Why does <C, X> have a count of "1" and not "2"?

Comment: The round trip has to be considered as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        case when Country1 < Country2 then Country1 else Country2 end as Country1,
        case when Country1 < Country2 then Country2 else Country1 end as Country2
    from Table1
)
select
    Country1, Country2, count(*)
from cte
group by Country1, Country2
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bd09/2)

Comment: hm, I've just seen that it's not doing what you ask, check again. Either the qustion or answer is wrong :)

Comment: @Mani please check again. I'll change my answer if this is not what you need

Comment: It doesnt give the exact result, but it gave me idea how to tweak it to get what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the round trips using correlated subquery, then do the simple grouping:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Country1, 
  t1.Country2,
  COUNT(*) AS Trips
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t1.Country1 = t2.Country2 
      AND t1.Country2 = t2.Country1
      AND t1.Country1 > t1.Country2
   )
GROUP BY t1.Country1, t1.Country2
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bd09/2)**